# Caffe: Reading LMDB from Python

Tags: python, caffe, lmdb

I've extracted features using caffe, which generates a .mdb file.
Then I'm trying to read it using Python and display it as a readable number.

```
import lmdb

lmdb_env = lmdb.open('caffefeat')
lmdb_txn = lmdb_env.begin()
lmdb_cursor = lmdb_txn.cursor()

for key, value in lmdb_cursor:
    print str(value)
```

This prints out a very long line of unreadable, broken characters.

Then I tried printing int(value), which returns the following:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x08\x80 \x10\x01\x18\x015\x8d\x80\xad?5'
```

float(value) gives the following:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:? 5????5
```

Is this a problem with the lmdb file itself, or does it have to do with conversion of data type?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's the working code I figured out

```
import caffe
import lmdb

lmdb_env = lmdb.open('directory_containing_mdb')
lmdb_txn = lmdb_env.begin()
lmdb_cursor = lmdb_txn.cursor()
datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()

for key, value in lmdb_cursor:
    datum.ParseFromString(value)
    label = datum.label
    data = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
    for l, d in zip(label, data):
            print l, d
```

Comment: I got error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 29367 into shape (0,0,0)`. I am using python2 under anaconda2, and installed caffe using `conda install caffe`

Comment: Can I provide only the path for the mdb file instad of its folder?

Answer (score 17):

If you have encoded images in `lmdb`, you'll probably see this error when using @ytrewq's code

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Use this function instead:

```
import caffe
import lmdb
import PIL.Image
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

def read_lmdb(lmdb_file):
    cursor = lmdb.open(lmdb_file, readonly=True).begin().cursor()
    datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
    for _, value in cursor:
        datum.ParseFromString(value)
        s = StringIO()
        s.write(datum.data)
        s.seek(0)

        yield np.array(PIL.Image.open(s)), datum.label
```

Example:

```
lmdb_dir = '/save/jobs/20160613-125532-958f/train_db/'
for im, label in read_lmdb(lmdb_dir):
    print label, im
```

Comment: Does this error you are solving here stem from lmdb created with encoded images?

Comment: @Shai Yes, see the [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/digits-users/CzHG1aHizsw/QYE3qWpxBgAJ)

Comment: Thank you for linking to the relevant thread. adds a proper context here. Can you please edit your answer to reflect it's relevance to encoded `lmdb`s? It is very good to state both the error message as well as the root cause: encoded images in lmdb. Thanks!

Comment: Done ! Thank you for the advice

Comment: Tried running and got the error `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Unexpected end-group tag.` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This answer saved me, and I got error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 29367 into shape (0,0,0)`