# Caffe & python, reading LMDB with complex label structure

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I have two LMDB files, with the first one my network trains fine while with the other one doesn't really work (loss starts and stays at 0). So I figured that maybe there's something wrong with the second LMDB. I tried writing some python code (mostly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117607/caffe-reading-lmdb-from-python)) to fetch the data from my LMDBs and inspect it but so far no luck with any of the 2 databases. The LMDBs contain images as data and bounding box information as labels.

Doing this:

```
for key, value in lmdb_cursor:
    datum.ParseFromString(value)
    label = datum.label
    data = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
```

on either one of the LMDBs gives me a key which is correctly the name of the image, but that `datum.ParseFromString` function is not able to retrieve anything from `value`. `label` is always 0, while data is an empty ndarray. Nonetheless, the data is there, value is a binary string of around 140 KB which correctly accounts for the size of the image plus the bounding box information I guess.

I tried browsing several answers and discussions dealing with reading data from LMDBs in python, but I couldn't find any clue on how to read structured information such as bounding box labels. My guess is that the parsing function expects a digit label and interprets the first bytes as such, with the remaining data being then lost due to the binary string not making any sense anymore?

I know for a fact that at least the first LMDB is correct since my network performs correctly in both training and testing using it.

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how did you write those LMDBs?

Comment: using the provided script `caffe/scripts/create_annoset.py` with `anno-type detection`. Bounding box information is encoded in xml using the Pascal VOC format.

Comment: in caffe/master branch there is no such script (as far as I can see). What branch of caffe are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm using the ssd caffe branch https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic element stored in your LMDB is not [`Datum`](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30-L41), but rather [`AnnotatedDatum`](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L144-L155). Threfore, you need to approach it with a little care:

```
datum.ParseFromString(value.datum)
value.annotation_group  # should store the annotations
```