# Caffe-terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' while building a Cat/Dog Classifier using a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, caffe

I am following [this tutorial](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/) to build cat-dog classifier using caffe. But while training I got this error;[image] why?

Comment: please do not post screen shots - copy-paste the run log and error message. Search engines cannot index screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got `"std::bad_alloc"` usually refers to CPU memory allocation: you are out of memory.
Judging by the stack trace, you got the error when trying to read an element from the LMDB file. You need to check your LMDB: is it possible you store HUGE images there? is it possible the LMDB is corrupt? can you read it with different software?

Comment: thank you for your reply, in train_lmdb I have stored 23000 images and there are data.mdb and lock.mdb both are 8.2kB in size. how can I read it with different software? which software I can use for it? @Shai

Comment: @Cham (1) it does not make sense that lmdb stores 23K images in only 8.2kB. (2) you can use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123313/1714410) to scan your lmdb

Comment: (1) yeah, I thought about it. (2) I'll check this one @Shai

Comment: when run that script it doesn't print any. Doesn't give any error. But under problems it says "Datum has no data member" @Shai

Comment: @Cham how did you construct your lmdb? it seems like it is corrupted. the entries have only "label" but no image?

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/adilmoujahid/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/blob/master/code/create_lmdb.py)  this is used @Shai

Comment: @Cham I guess you'll have to debug it. did you get any error/warning messages when you created the lmdb?

Comment: no nothing, they were created nicely without showing any error messages @Sham

Comment: @Sham use a debuger to check the creation of your lmdb: i suspect there were no imagefiles found at all and you basically have an empty dataset.

Comment: I debugged, doesn't show any error. I followed above mentioned tutorial, still can't think what happened. @Shai

Comment: Though I installed opencv and import it, always show below messages; Module cv2 has no '...' member . Is this affect this problem? @Shai